# SetUbiquitous showing 'file already exists' for file that doesn't

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, appdelegate

In `AppDelegate.swift`, on first launch, the intent is to place some sample docs in the local Documents folder, or in the iCloud Documents folder if iCloud is enabled.

```
    var templates = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathsForResourcesOfType(AppDelegate.myExtension, inDirectory: "Templates")
    dispatch_async(appDelegateQueue) {
        self.ubiquityURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier(nil)
        if self.ubiquityURL != nil && templates.count != 0 {
            // Move sample documents from Templates to iCloud directory on initial launch
            for template in templates {
                let tempurl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: template)
                let title = tempurl.URLByDeletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent

                    let ubiquitousDestinationURL = self.ubiquityURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(title!).URLByAppendingPathExtension(AppDelegate.myExtension)
                    // let exists = NSFileManager().isUbiquitousItemAtURL(ubiquitousDestinationURL!)
                    do {
                        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().setUbiquitous(true, itemAtURL: tempurl, destinationURL: ubiquitousDestinationURL!)
                    }
                    catch let error as NSError {
                        print("Failed to move file \(title!) to iCloud: \(error)")
                    }
            }
        }
        return
    }
```

Before running this, I delete the app from the device and make sure no doc of that name is in iCloud. On first launch, without iCloud, the sample docs copy properly into the local Documents folder. With iCloud, this code runs, and the `setUbiquitous` call results in an error that says the file already exists. The commented call to `isUbiquitousItemAtURL` also returns true.

What might be making these calls register that a file exists that I'm pretty sure doesn't? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The file already exists, so just replace it

Comment: There's no other evidence of them existing. The meta query that shows cloud files doesn't find them, but finds all other docs. Can't find them through the Mac's file system (iCloud folder). Can't find them with iMazing. I do get that it's finding something that makes it generate that error, but I can't figure out what or where.

Answer (score 0):

The primary solution...in all the trial and error, I'd forgotten to put "Documents" back in the url. Should be:

```
let ubiquitousDestinationURL = self.ubiquityURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Documents").URLByAppendingPathComponent(title!).URLByAppendingPathExtension(AppDelegate.myExtension)
```

Without that, wrote the file to the wrong directory, and so I couldn't see it by normal means.